# What does exactly "scan_num" function in "emu8086.inc" do?

Tags: assembly, x86, emulation

I'm working with emu8086, in a source code I've found this line at the top:

```
include 'emu8086.inc'
```

and this line in the end:

```
DEFINE_SCAN_NUM
```

I know that scan num is a part of emu8086.inc, and I opened up the inc file with an editor but still can't figure out what does exactly scan_function do?

Comment: Will [this](http://www.emu8086.com/assembler_tutorial/asm_tutorial_05.html) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reads a number between -32767 and 32767 and returns it into CX, using BIOS functions for keyboard input and display of the number.

(Actually, it will accept the `-` sign at any position, not only at the start).

Answer (score 1):

To use `scan_num`, we need to declare `DEFINE_SCAN_NUM` before `END`. And `scan_num` procedure helps us to take input from keyboard.

Comment: From this, I assume the `.inc` file doesn't come with a separate library you have to link, but  `scan_num` is too big to be good as a macro that inlines wherever you use it.  But they can't define a function in a `.inc` in case you include that in multiple files, then you'd have conflicting symbol definitions.  So they just define a macro `DEFINE_SCAN_NUM` that expands to a function definition, and you choose where to put that, in exactly one file in your project.